# Writing in a text file using java swing

Tags: java, text-files, newline

I'm having a problem with writing a text file using Java swing. Below is my code, if I try to open the file the text isn't formatted like its supposed to, going into a new line after each input text. I've tried using /n, System.lineSeparator() and %n, but nothing seems to work. Unless I copy the content into another file it looks wrong. Instead of going into a new line it gives me this:

Name: Bob Test
Number: 12345678
Email: BobTest@email.com

Address: 
Teststreet 123
TestCity
Testcountry

Gender: Male
Occupation: Student
Salary: 500
Manager: Yes

```
try {
                        Object fileName = textField.getText();
                        File user = new File("C:\\Users\\Nicol\\Desktop\\"+fileName+".txt");
                        if(!user.exists()) {
                            user.createNewFile();
                        } 
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(user);
            pw.print("Name: ");
            textField.write(pw);
            pw.print("\nNumber: ");
            textField_1.write(pw);
            pw.print("\nEmail: ");
            textField_3.write(pw);
            pw.print("\n\nAddress: \n");
            textArea.write(pw);
            if(rdbtnMale.isSelected()) {
                pw.print("\n\nGender: Male");
            }else if(rdbtnFemale.isSelected()) {
                pw.print("\n\nGender: Female");
            }else {
                pw.print("\n\nGender: none selected");
            }
            Object professionSelect = comboBox.getSelectedItem();   
            pw.print("\nOccupation: " + professionSelect);

            pw.print("\nSalary: ");
            textField_4.write(pw);
            if(chckbxIsManager.isSelected()) {
            pw.print("\nManager: Yes");
            }
            else {
                pw.print("\nManager: No");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The file has been created on the desktop.");
            pw.close();

                    }
```

Comment: Don't use `\n`. Use `println(...)` instead

Comment: And the question doesn't appear to have anything to do with Swing